# Maximum request length exceeded ASP.NET Core Mvc 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, iis-8, asp.net-core-2.1

I keep getting this error when uploading a file via AJAX, smaller files work of course. I've read the solution is to update the max request setting on IIS8. Well that works, except it gets overwritten EVERY TIME I publish the site.

So what can I do so the setting sticks?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267 try these options

Comment: Yeah. Not *one* of those solutions worked. The *only* thing that works is manually editing web.config and adding:
<security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
        <fileExtensions>
          <add fileExtension=".ashx" allowed="false" />
          <add fileExtension=".asmx" allowed="false" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>  The problem is whenever I publish the site those setting are overwritten. How do I set maxAllowedContentLength in my MVC 6 project?